# Was I wrong to ask on SE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm new to SE. And I realized that we have to research our questions first before asking them on SE. So that we can provide more information about what we asked, so it's more reasonable and easier to be answered.

Because sometimes questions became closed, or on-hold, or duplicate because of reasons like, "*research-less*" or "*having an exact duplicate of an existing question*". And there are many questions that started with, "*I've checked lots of dictionaries ... Here are my researches..*".

I don’t know, though.. Sometimes we can answer our own questions without asking them on SE. For example, you can answer some grammatical English questions by searching them on [this site](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/grammar-girl) or [this one](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en). That means, when a question crossed in your head, it could had been answered on those sites. And it conveys that if you ask it on SE, you should be considered as duplicating someone's question.

So I asked [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134664/whats-the-meaning-of-as-many-as) on ELL.SE. And a user commented: "*why don't you just google it?*" Then I replied to him:

> No matter how *advanced* or *basic* your question is, there could be someone that had asked or answered that question on internet.
>   Well, I, myself, knew this site by asking some stuff on Google. And this site appeared as the top search result. Followed by some other sites that also answer the same question. That means, by asking an interesting/common question that hadn't been asked before on this site (but actually had on other sites) could bring us more new people/users.

But I respect our *culture* in SE to research our questions first. But sometimes you can find everything on the internet (Google). Was I wrong to ask [that question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/134664/whats-the-meaning-of-as-many-as)?

Comment: We have a help center article on how to ask good questions - https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: But one of the very basic rules of SE - you are expected to do *some* research before asking a question. If it is something that it is reasonable for a person to find via google - it probably isn't a suitable SE question.

Comment: By you said "*If it is something that it is reasonable for a person to find via google - it probably isn't a suitable SE question*", I actually found **many** questions on ELL or ELU that could be answered by simply googling it.

Comment: What can I say? They too are probably not a good fit.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-windows/info

Comment: @Oded ELL (and likely other language-learning sites) is a bit of a special case. Many of the users we have on ELL have a difficult time finding the results they need for the very reason that they're not native English speakers. We do require basic research, such as not asking what X word means - that's what a dictionary is for - but we are generally pretty lenient about requiring research. ELU is generally more hard core about requiring research but it really depends on who's around. Some people are more picky than others.

Comment: @IvanDi I strongly encourage you to bring topics like this that relate specifically to a site to **that site's** meta, first. [ell.meta.se] is a great place to ask this because, as I've just pointed out, things tend to be a bit more lenient on ELL.

Comment: Both ELU and ELL have a heterogonous user base and comprise both native speakers and NNSs. But, yeah, *things tend to be a bit more lenient on ELL*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, as useful as the internet is, and as much information as there is out there, the internet does not in fact have the entirety of knowledge in existence.  There are still lots of questions that can't be answered by searching Google.

SE isn't here to duplicate content from other sites and try to get more SEO than them.  It's here to *add to the total knowledge of the internet* and actually *add value* by providing content that *isn't* already readily accessible with a simple web search.

So yes, you *are* wrong to ask a question that's trivially answered by simply searching Google first.  Do your research, as you've been told to do so before.  Clearly you already knew that it was expected of you, and you choose to flagrantly disregard the site's rules.  Don't do that.

Comment: What if I want more opinions on the matter that I asked?

Comment: @IvanDi It's not appropriate to ask for opinions on SE, so if you're question is just looking for opinions then it's not on topic here.

Comment: Ah.. So we're not allowed to do that. It seems like I need to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) all over again. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanDi If you Googled a question and found answers that don't work, include that in your  question and explain why they don't work for you; describing the research you did already is a big part of what makes a good question into a great question.